# How to Parse/get Ajax delayed response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the response code for an email form I sent to a PHP mailer page with ajax. If the mail is sent successfully it echos 1 else 0.

Here is how I send the from

```
$('form.ajax-form').on('submit', function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    method: $form.attr('method'),
    data:$form.serialize(),
    success: function(response){
      if (response == '1' ) {
        M.toast({html: 'I am a toast!'});
      }else if (response == '0') {
        M.toast({html: 'I am not a toast!'});
      }
    },
  });
});
```

Depending on the response I want to execute `M.toast({html: 'I am a toast!'});` but i cant get the response even if the PHP mailer echos 1 or 0. It takes 4 seconds for the mailer to echo the response. I have tried `delay : 4` Still can't get the response. What am i doing wrong ? Please Help. Thank you.

UPDATE.

Here are the response from XHR.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried sending sync call instead of async by setting async:false ?

Comment: New to ajax here... Let me try.

Comment: @umer .. Still the same issue.

Comment: try : console.log(response); // for debug the Ajax response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$('form.ajax-form').on('submit', function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    method: $form.attr('method'),
    data:$form.serialize(),
    success: function(response){
      if ($.trim(response) === '0') {
        M.toast({html: 'I am not a toast!'});
      }else{
        M.toast({html: 'I am a toast!'});
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I Modified your Code and it works well.

Comment: Cool. Please, Submit my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code.

```
$('form.ajax-form').on('submit', function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    method: $form.attr('method'),
    data:$form.serialize(),
    async:false,
    success: function(response){
      if ($.trim(response) === '1') {
        M.toast({html: 'I am a toast!'});
      }else if ($.trim(response) === '0') {
        M.toast({html: 'I am a not toast!'});
      }
    },
  });
});
```

Had to trim the response and set async:false, and its working now.